# JSF 2 composite component, passing attributes to backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I'm stuck on simple JSF2 question:

XHTML:

```
<xvf:simpleOut identifier="12345"/>
```

Composite component is supposed to pass "12345" to backing bean and do some output:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="identifier" required="true" type="java.lang.String"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <!--@elvariable id="arg" type="java.lang.String"-->
    <ui:param name="arg" value="#{cc.attrs.identifier}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{myBean.getTestOutput('???????')}"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

How do I pass `identifier` value, '12345' in my case, to bean's `getTestOutput(String arg)` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `<ui:param>` tag at all. This should work:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.getTestOutput(cc.attrs.identifier)}"/>
```

But it might a a good idea to pass `myBean` through the interface as well rather than refering to it directly, since it would make the composite component reusable.

Comment: Thanks, you've saved my day! It's new to me that cc.attrs.*, unlike elvariables, can be passed to backing beans.

Comment: @Osw: I'm not sure what you mean by "unlike elvariables". If a variable can be resolved by an EL Resolver, it can be passed to a method - *if* your JSF container supports method parameters in EL expression, which is only available in EL 2.2.

Comment: you're right. My fault is that I've used nested el expressions like '#{myBean.getTestOutput(#{arg})}'. Thanks again.