# How do I pass an attribute from composite component to backing bean by using backing component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have the following code in my facelet page:

```
  <hc:rangeChooser1 id="range_chooser" 
                    from="#{testBean.from}"
                    to="#{testBean.to}"
                    listener="#{testBean.update}"
                    text="#{testBean.text}">
        <f:ajax event="rangeSelected"
                execute="@this"
                listener="#{testBean.update}"                   
                render=":form:growl range_chooser"/>
    </hc:rangeChooser1>
```

This is my composite component:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <cc:interface componentType="rangeChooser">
        <!-- Define component attributes here -->
        <cc:clientBehavior name="rangeSelected" event="change" targets="hiddenValue"/>
        <cc:attribute name="from" type="java.util.Calendar"/>
        <cc:attribute name="to" type="java.util.Calendar"/>
        <cc:attribute name="text" type="java.lang.String"/>

    </cc:interface>


    <cc:implementation>

        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
                 ...
                <p:inputText id="hiddenValue" value="#{cc.attrs.text}"/>
                 ...
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

How do I pass attributes `from`, `to` and `text` from composite component to backing bean? I mean inject these values in backing component, and not through

```
<p:inputText id="hiddenValue" value="#{cc.attrs.text}"/>
```

**Update: there's more correct definition what do I need:** Be able to mutate objects which I pass from the `backing bean` to the `composite component` inside a `backing component` of the `composite component`. So when I perform `process` or `execute` my `composite component` I get the updated values.

This is  my backing component:

```
@FacesComponent("rangeChooser")
public class RangeChooser extends UIInput implements NamingContainer  {
    private String text;
    private Calendar from;
    private Calendar to;

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException{

        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }


    public String getText() {
        String text = (String)getStateHelper().get(PropertyKeys.text);
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.text, text);
    }

    /*
        same getters and setters for Calendar objects, from and to
    */

}
```

I just can't realize how do I move on? In general I need to take a value from `<p:inputText id="hiddenValue" value="#{cc.attrs.text}"/>` and convert it to two Calendars object `from` and `to`.
It will be great if somebody can point me toward right direction from here. **I know that I need to use  `getAttributes().put(key,value)` but don't know where to put this code.** Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460524/jsf-2-composite-component-passing-attributes-to-backing-bean i think this is will help you. ;)

Comment: It's not so clear what you want to accomplish. Are `from` and `to` inputs and is `text` an output string representation of the range?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, no **from** and **to** should be to `Calendar` objects. When I change **Range** in a **composite component**, it should change these values in backing bean too. Text is just for testing purposes. Actually I already know how to perform this but if I encapsulate `from` and `to` in a single object, and set it via `getSubmittedValue`, but I doubt can it be done in two objects separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comments this is what you expect.

Note that even if this implementation works, it is **conceptually incorrect!**

You are considering `from` and `to` as INPUTS (not input components, but input values) and `text` as OUTPUT. This is not the way JSF is intended to work!

However, here it is

```
<cc:interface componentType="rangeComponent">
    <cc:attribute name="from" />
    <cc:attribute name="to" />
    <cc:clientBehavior name="rangeSelected" event="dateSelect" targets="from to"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <p:calendar id="from" value="#{cc.attrs.from}"/>
        <p:calendar id="to" value="#{cc.attrs.to}"/>
    </div>

</cc:implementation>
```

used in page:

```
<h:form>
    <e:inputRange from="#{rangeBean.from}" to="#{rangeBean.to}" text="#{rangeBean.text}">
        <p:ajax event="rangeSelected" process="@namingcontainer" update="@form:output" listener="#{rangeBean.onChange}" />
    </e:inputRange>

    <h:panelGrid id="output" columns="1">
        <h:outputText value="#{rangeBean.from}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{rangeBean.to}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{rangeBean.text}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

with this backing component:

```
@FacesComponent("rangeComponent")
public class RangeComponent extends UINamingContainer
{
    @Override
    public void processUpdates(FacesContext context)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(context);

        if(!isRendered())
        {
            return;
        }

        super.processUpdates(context);

        try
        {
            Date from = (Date) getValueExpression("from").getValue(context.getELContext());
            Date to = (Date) getValueExpression("to").getValue(context.getELContext());

            ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression("text");
            if(ve != null)
            {
                ve.setValue(context.getELContext(), from + " - " + to);
            }
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            context.renderResponse();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

with this backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RangeBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date from = new Date(1000000000);
    private Date to = new Date(2000000000);
    private String text = "range not set";

    public void onChange(SelectEvent event)
    {
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("[{0}] changed: [{1}]", event.getComponent().getId(), event.getObject());
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Hi, it not exactly what do I need, I've written: How do I pass attributes from, to and text from composite component to backing bean? **I mean inject these values in backing component**, and not through
`<p:inputText id="hiddenValue" value="#{cc.attrs.text}"/>`, it's useful when I need to encapsulate some business logic inside backing component.

Comment: You probably are misusing the word **inject**, which is commonly related to container-managed annotations like `@ManagedProperty`, `@Inject`, `@EJB`, ... clarify inject and maybe I'll can help :)

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I meant to mutate objects which I pass from `backing bean` to `composite component` inside `backing component` of `composite component`. Perhaps this definition is more correct, I will edit my post.

Comment: Hi, Now I agree with you now that it's conceptually incorrect. I just didn't know it before this. The right solution will to encapsulate `datamodel` object in a single object and work with it by `getSubmittedValue`. Anyway, I've learnt a lot from your code, so thank you very much for you effort. Btw, your solution only partially works, it does update `text` field, and does update `from` field. But `to` field doesn't updated, but I get correct value in `SelectEvent` inside `RangeBean`. And It didn't update 'pangelGrid', only  `<h:outputText>` one at time. Again, thank you for your effort!

Comment: JSF sometimes can be very counterintuitive... I think a better solution is to use the approch of [PrimeFaces range slider](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml)  (bottom of page) rendering two calendars instead of a slider, though it can be a lot of work... I'd avoid `DataModel` (it's for `Collection`s iteration) and either `get/setSubmittedValue` (should be used in Custom Components, not in Composite, generally). However, in my environment (JDK 1.7.0_51, Glassfish 4.1, Mojarra 2.2.8-r3, PrimeFaces 5.1), it works completely.

Comment: Can you advice when I should make `Composite Component and when `Custom`. Making a Composite Component much simpler than Custom Component, even @BalusC promotes this approach here: http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html In my case I have specific requirement for **Range Chooser**, so I couldn't use Primefaces's components. I implemented it by using `JQuery Datepicker` with customization and wrapped it in `Composite Component`. I think that general approach here: "if you can make it by using `Composite Component`, do it with it. Am I right?

Comment: Using an advanced composite like @BalusC in his article is a far better idea, see the other answer. Too bad you can't use PrimeFaces... so you are forced to reinvent the wheel!

Answer (score 4):

I rewrote the code using BalusC tecnique (and without PrimeFaces):

the form:

```
<h:form>
    <e:inputRange value="#{rangeBean.range}">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@namingcontainer" update="@form:output"
            listener="#{rangeBean.onChange}" />
    </e:inputRange>

    <h:panelGrid id="output" columns="1">
        <h:outputText value="#{rangeBean.range}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

the composite:

```
<cc:interface componentType="rangeComponent">
    <cc:attribute name="value" />
    <cc:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="from to"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <h:inputText id="from" binding="#{cc.from}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:inputText id="to" binding="#{cc.to}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </h:inputText>
    </div>

</cc:implementation>
```

the backing component:

```
@FacesComponent("rangeComponent")
public class RangeComponent extends UIInput implements NamingContainer
{
    private UIInput from;
    private UIInput to;

    @Override
    public String getFamily()
    {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException
    {
        String value = (String) getValue();
        if(value != null)
        {
            String fromString = StringUtils.substringBefore(value, "-");
            String toString = StringUtils.substringAfter(value, "-");

            try
            {
                from.setValue(from.getConverter().getAsObject(context, from, fromString));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                from.setValue(new Date());
            }

            try
            {
                to.setValue(to.getConverter().getAsObject(context, to, toString));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                to.setValue(new Date());
            }
        }

        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue()
    {
        return (from.isLocalValueSet() ? from.getValue() : from.getSubmittedValue()) + "-" + (to.isLocalValueSet() ? to.getValue() : to.getSubmittedValue());
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object submittedValue)
    {
        return from.getSubmittedValue() + "-" + to.getSubmittedValue();
    }

    public UIInput getFrom()
    {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(UIInput from)
    {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public UIInput getTo()
    {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(UIInput to)
    {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

and the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RangeBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String range = "01/01/2015-31/12/2015";

    public void onChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("[{0}] changed: [{1}]", event.getComponent().getId(), event.getBehavior());
    }

    public String getRange()
    {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(String range)
    {
        this.range = range;
    }
}
```

Note that managed bean only retains `range` property for get/set. `From` and `to` are gone, the backing component derives and rebuilds them itself.