# How to extend AjaxBehaviorEvent dispatched from @FacesComponent?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

When I dispatch an **ajax** event from the **Composite Component** by using  `<cc:clientBehavior name="chartUpdated" event="change" targets="chartdata"/>` I catch it in **Facelet page** by using `<f:ajax event="chartUpdated" listener="#{bean.updateListener}">`. And In **backing bean** I capture event of type **AjaxBehaviorEvent**.

```
public void updateListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
      ...
}
```

I undertand that I can extend **AjaxBehaviorEvent** and pass within it object which has been changed. [For example, Primefaces's Scheduler uses this approach:](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml)

```
  <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
```

And backing bean:

```
 public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

        addMessage(message);
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality by using **Composite Component** together with the **@FacesComponent** ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice to meet you, again :)

continuing from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706635/how-do-i-pass-an-attribute-from-composite-component-to-backing-bean-by-using-bac):

Override `queueEvent()` to filter interesting events (changes from specific components) and postpone their enqueue to validation phase to be able to fetch converted & validated values:

```
@FacesComponent("rangeComponent")
public class RangeComponent extends UIInput implements NamingContainer
{
    private final List<AjaxBehaviorEvent> customEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    ...

    @Override
    public void queueEvent(FacesEvent event)
    {
        FacesContext context = getFacesContext();
        if(event instanceof AjaxBehaviorEvent)
        {
            Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            String eventName = params.get("javax.faces.behavior.event");
            Object eventSource = event.getSource();

            if("change".equals(eventName) && (from.equals(eventSource) || to.equals(eventSource)))
            {
                customEvents.add((AjaxBehaviorEvent) event);
                return;
            }
        }

        super.queueEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context)
    {
        super.validate(context);

        if(from.isValid() && to.isValid())
        {
            for(AjaxBehaviorEvent event : customEvents)
            {
                SelectEvent selectEvent = new SelectEvent(this, event.getBehavior(), this.getValue());

                if(event.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES))
                {
                    selectEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS);
                }
                else
                {
                    selectEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
                }

                super.queueEvent(selectEvent);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

then add the specific event listener to your managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RangeBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String range = "01/01/2015-31/12/2015";

    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event)
    {
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("[{0}] selected: [{1}]", event.getComponent().getId(), event.getObject());
    }

    public String getRange()
    {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(String range)
    {
        this.range = range;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me too :) Thank you for your help. I've implemented your solution without implementing **validate** method, and it's working fine. What am I missing?

Comment: It depends on phase. If the event is triggered in `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase (like "change" events), calls to `component.getValue()` return an obsolete value. Otherwise there's no need to postpone, i.e. "valueChange" events are triggered in `PROCESS_VALIDATIONS` phase.

Comment: Noted should be that this approach is tight coupled to PrimeFaces due to the `Constants`. If you intend the component to be reusable across all component libraries, you'd better remove PrimeFaces-specific imports.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, it was a few deadlines at work and I just now can finally implement your solution. I've a question, why do you use **array** `customEvents`? And how and when it should be cleaned up? If after call to `Validate`, do we need `array` at all? Can it be possible to process few events at same time?

Comment: `customEvents` is a temporary storage between different methods invocations (and possibly different lifecycle phases). There's no need to clean it up since components are request scoped, and however, yes, it can be cleaned at the end of `validate()` because it's not used anymore in the same request. Yes, it's possible to process few events at the same time, in a serial manner.